# Alamofire Router and URLRequestConvertible

Tags: alamofire

I'm having trouble converting my ObjectiveC AFNetworking `Request` and `Response Serializers` to something in line with Alamofire best practices. I have several different endpoints that I need to connect to, and two of them share the same `OAuth1` authentication system, but their request formats are different. How would I design a system around `URLRequestConvertible` that would allow me to share the `OAuth` authentication code with the 2 Routers that are specific to their endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start is the [Advanced Section](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#advanced-usage) in Alamofire README. There are some good examples of how to start designing a `Router` type.

From there, you should post some sample code that we can work with you on. That way we can tell exactly what you're trying to do.